# Google Charts Category Filter - Hide html tags or convert the elements to links

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

Is anybody  has an idea how the html tags can be hidden or can be converted to html links  in the category filter ? I am having the following issue:

In the chart table for  one of the columns I am providing html links. I am setting the property `allowHtml:true` in the `ChartWrapper()`. In the table the links are displaying properly.  When I put filtering on that column  the dropdown is getting the whole value of the column  including the html. Unfortunately there isn't a property allowHtml for the `ControlWrapper()`.
Here is how the filter is looking.

[Screenshot of the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwXZx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove the html from the `CategoryFilter`,
for each cell in the data table column,
use the value property (`v:`) for the value to be displayed in the filter,
and the formatted value property (`f:`) for the link

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Link', type: 'string'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 'Test 1', f: '<a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 1</a>'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Test 2', f: '<a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 2</a>'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Test 3', f: '<a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 3</a>'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Test 4', f: '<a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 4</a>'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Test 5', f: '<a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 5</a>'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Test 6', f: '<a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 6</a>'}]}
      ]
    });

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('dashboard')
    );

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
      containerId: 'control',
      options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0,
        ui: {
          allowTyping: false,
        }
      }
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'table',
      options: {
        allowHtml: true
      }
    });

    dashboard.bind(control, chart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
  },
  packages: ['controls', 'table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="control"></div>
  <div id="table"></div>
</div>
```

---

*note:* not sure how to get the actual link to display in the filter,
but that could interfere with actually selecting a value anyway

Comment: Thank you very much, WhiteHat ! This helped me a lot !  :)